# A little proposition for Galois representations on a local field of Diamond-Shurman's book

Tags: number-theory, representation-theory, algebraic-number-theory, modular-forms, galois-representations

$\def\gl{\mathrm{GL}}
\def\Q{\mathbb{Q}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\gal}{Gal}
$

I am reading the Galois representation chapter of Diamond-Shurman "A first course in modular forms".

Let $L$ be a finite extension of a $\ell$-adic number field $\Q_{\ell}$. It is well known that $L$ can be expressed in a form $L=K_{\lambda}$ using a certain number field $K$ and its ideal $\lambda \mid \ell$. Let $G_{\Q}=\gal(\bar{\Q}/\Q)$ be the absolute Galois group of $\Q$.

> **Proposition 9.3.5.** Let $\rho :G_{\Q}\to \gl_d(L)$ be a Galois
> representation. Then $\rho$ is "similar to" a Galois representation
> $\rho' :G_{\Q}\to \gl_d(\mathcal{O}_L)$.

First of all,I was not sure what "similar to" meant, because the book seems to use the word "equivalent" to express isomorphism as an representation.

Secondly, I could not understand the part of the proof enclosed by "" below. I quote the proof as follows:

> **Proof.**  Let $V=L^d$ and let $\Lambda=\mathcal{O}_{L}^d$.
>
> Then $\Lambda$ is a lattice of $V$, hence a finitely generated
> $\mathbb{Z}_{\ell}$-module, hence compact as noted at the end of
> Section 9.2.
>
> Since $G_{\mathbb{Q}}$ is compact as well, so is the image
> $\Lambda^{\prime}$ of $\Lambda \times G_{\mathbb{Q}}$ under the map $V
>  \times$ $G_{\mathbb{Q}} \longrightarrow V$. Thus "the image lies in
> $\lambda^{-r} \Lambda$ for some $r \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$". "The image is
> finitely generated, it contains $\Lambda$" so its rank is at least
> $d$, it is free since $\mathcal{O}_{L}$ is a principal ideal domain,
> and so its rank is exactly $d$.
>
> "It is taken to itself by $G_{\mathbb{Q}}$". All of this combines to
> show that "any $\mathcal{O}_{L}$-basis of $\Lambda^{\prime}$ gives the
> desired $\rho^{\prime}$".

Please break the proof down for me.

Answer (score 3):

Similar means finding $P\in GL_d(L)$ such that $\forall g\in G_\Bbb{Q},\rho'(g)=P \rho(g) P^{-1}$.

$(g,v)\mapsto \rho(g) v$ is meant to be continuous $ G_\Bbb{Q}\times L^d\to L^d$.

The point is that $G_\Bbb{Q}$ and $O_L^d$ are both compact, so $W$ the $O_L$-module generated by $\{ \rho(g)v, (g,v)\in G_\Bbb{Q}\times O_L^d\}$ is compact. This implies that $W$ is contained in $\ell^{-r} O_L^d$ for some $r$.

$O_L$ is a PID, so $\ell^{-r} O_L^d\supset W \supset O_L^d$ implies that $W$ is a rank $d$  free $O_L$ module, ie. there is some $P\in GL_d(L)$ such that $W=P O_L^d$.

That's it, letting $\rho'(g)= P \rho(g) P^{-1}$ then both $\rho'(g),\rho'(g)^{-1}$ are $L$-linear maps $O_L^d\to O_L^d$ ie. $\forall g\in G_\Bbb{Q},\rho'(g)\in GL_d(O_L)$.

Comment: Does this mean "equivalent"="similar"="isomorphic as representations"?

Also, I already asked, why does $W$ contain $\ell^{-r}\mathcal{O}_L^d$ if $W$ is compact? (Again, this looks different from the book's description.) And I think the next sentence also has the terms at both ends reversed.

Also, if "$W=P\mathcal{O}_L^d$" (which I interpreted to mean that $P$ is the basis transformation matrix), why is $\rho'(g)\in GL_d(\mathcal{O}_L)$?

Thanks.